# Best way to filter a day with NSPredicateEditor

Tags: macos, nspredicateeditor

Did anyone come around a solution for filtering data ( CoreData ) by a day, using NSPredicateEditor ? The idea is to make it most convenient to the user. The standard solution would be to define 2 criteria for date :

1. one for >= start of the day
2. another one for <= end of the day.

One EditorRowTemplate should simply look like:

- left expression = aDate (property of a Core Data entity )
- rightexpression = Dates

[image]

Then, the app should convert the predicate to somewhat like:

```
"aDate >= '3.5.20210 00:00:00' AND aDate <= '3.5.20210 23:59:59'".
```

Of course, it should take the value from the date which the user has entered in the row template.

I thought, closures can be a way. So to say, creating the NSPredicate programmatically.
But how to use it in NSExpression and grabbing the date from the input ?

The desired row template should look like this :

[image]

Comment: How about a `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` subclass?

Comment: Yes, this is my approach. But I am struggeling with creating a templateView, keeping 2 entry fields. Under ObjectiveC, you could manipulate the views of the templates. Now templateViews() is only a getter function.

Comment: Do you want a row with two dates or do you want a row with one date and a predicate with two dates?

Comment: I would like to have a row with 2 dates which are editable, so that I can set the dates

Comment: Is the question "How to filter by a day" or "How to implement between"? How did you manipulate the views of the templates in Objective-C?

Comment: The question is: How to filter by a date. I have a property in my model (aDate) which keeps DATE and TIME information. With my Predicate I want to filter all entries on a particular date, means from the time 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. So I thought I need a between statement as shown above..

Comment: So the user sees a row with one date field and the row template converts the predicate?

Comment: Well, not so sure about the question.. I have a tableview showing Core Data . A NSPredicateEditor is just below to filter the data in various ways. One of it is to filter the date. The user should only enter the date in the format dd.mm.yy (day/month/day) , and the filter should convert it into BETWEEN day-00:00:00 to day-23:59:59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row template can convert the predicate in `predicate(withSubpredicates:)`, no other overrides required. In IB the right expressions are Dates.

```
override func predicate(withSubpredicates subpredicates: [NSPredicate]?) -> NSPredicate {
    // call super to get the predicate, for example aDate == '3.5.20210 14:03:53'
    let predicate = super.predicate(withSubpredicates: subpredicates)
    // convert the predicate to aDate >= '3.5.2021 00:00:00' AND aDate < '4.5.2021 00:00:00'
    var newPredicate = predicate
    if let comparisonPredicate = predicate as? NSComparisonPredicate,
        let predicateDate = comparisonPredicate.rightExpression.constantValue as? Date {
        let keyPath = comparisonPredicate.leftExpression.keyPath
        var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: predicateDate)
        components.hour = 0
        components.minute = 0
        components.second = 0
        components.calendar = NSCalendar.current
        switch comparisonPredicate.predicateOperatorType {
            case .lessThan:
                // aDate < '3.5.2021 00:00:00'
                let date = components.date! as NSDate
                newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K < %@", keyPath,date)
            case .lessThanOrEqualTo:
                // aDate < '4.5.2021 00:00:00'
                components.day = components.day! + 1
                let date = components.date! as NSDate
                newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K < %@", keyPath,date)
            case .greaterThan:
                // aDate >= '4.5.2021 00:00:00'
                components.day = components.day! + 1
                let date = components.date! as NSDate
                newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K >= %@", keyPath,date)
            case .greaterThanOrEqualTo:
                // aDate >= '3.5.2021 00:00:00'
                let date = components.date! as NSDate
                newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K >= %@", keyPath,date)
            case .equalTo:
                // aDate >= '3.5.2021 00:00:00' AND aDate < '4.5.2021 00:00:00'
                let startDate = components.date! as NSDate
                components.day = components.day! + 1
                let endDate = components.date! as NSDate
                newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K >= %@ AND %K < %@", keyPath, startDate, keyPath, endDate)
            case .notEqualTo:
                // NOT (aDate >= '3.5.2021 00:00:00' AND aDate < '4.5.2021 00:00:00')
                let startDate = components.date! as NSDate
                components.day = components.day! + 1
                let endDate = components.date! as NSDate
                newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (%K >= %@ AND %K < %@)", keyPath, startDate, keyPath, endDate)
            default:
                newPredicate = predicate
        }
    }
    return newPredicate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Willeke's answer I was able to solve it. I want to let you participate on the entire solution.

1. Create a custom class CustomRowTemplate: NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate
2. override func predicate, see Willeke's code above. This has access to the date you wish to filter
   and it creates the predicate with a date/time range for the day.

```
    override func predicate(withSubpredicates subpredicates: [NSPredicate]?) -> NSPredicate
```

3. In the attribute inspector, for the predicateEditor , create a new Rowtemplate for keypath and date.
   then change its class to CustomRowTemplate
4. That's all.